# vs code setup for beginners

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, installation, terminal, output

hi i'm a beginner and have just started programming have started with c i have some difficulties with getting output by pressing the play kinda button on top right corner

i tried to get the output but it [image]was showin like as shown in the img

Comment: What would you expect instead? Do you have some code you are trying to run?

Comment: Does it not put the output in the "output" window?

Comment: @EugeneSh. i do have code written and it was even working but in debug console so is it ok to get a output there insted of terminal

Comment: @ChrisBD no a error came out regarding the extension